# Seeking free EXIF component

Tags: delphi, exif

I have 100+ GB of photos going back 25 years. They are arranged in a directory tree by category, with nested sub-directories.

I want to a search for all photos taken in a given month, say April, in any of those directories.

I don't think that a Windows search will work as that will probably be the file creation data, which could be a month or two later wen I finally more the files from SD card to PC.

Perhaps searching the EXIF data? Is there a free VCL component which can help me to do that?

Comment: A few free components: [JPG Images. Torry's Delphi Pages](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=104&SID=a98f01a9d2ff194eeb70eb5f2dfe4249)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your EXIF data is good, Windows Search (at least in Vista/7, not as sure about Windows Search 4 in XP) should index it and allow you to query by it once you learn the correct syntax.  In Windows 7's Search something like "Date Taken:2011-04-01..2011-04-30" would probably work.

That said, for a more SO-specific answer to your question, [CCR Exif](https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/ccr-exif/) is a Delphi Class library for read/edit/delete of EXIF/IPTC/XMP metadata in pictures.  It's made available under the MPL 1.1.

You'll still have to write all the code to walk your directory tree and do your searching, but this can handle all the metadata work.

Comment: you miss my point, U don;t want to search for 2011-04-01..2011-04-30becasue there are too many years. Only for "april and I don't care which year", but _1 for the CCR EXIF, which I will check out. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see -- I assumed that when you said "April" you meant "the most recent April", not "any April".  That is a bit trickier!

Comment: +1 my own fault for not making it clearer. Judging by your upvotes others read it that way too. I will use CCR  http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/ccr-exif/